# Error in predict.segmented

Tags: r, regression, predict, piecewise

I was trying to make a prediction using segmented regression and it gives me an Error: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'U1.Sepal.Width' not found". What am I doing wrong?

Here is the sample code:

```
    library("segmented")
    data("iris")
    breaks <- list(Sepal.Width = quantile(iris$Sepal.Width, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)), 
                   Petal.Width = quantile(iris$Petal.Width, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))
    fit.lm <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, data = iris)
    fit.segmented <- segmented(fit.lm, seg.Z = ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, 
                                psi = breaks, control = seg.control(it.max = 0)) 
    summary(fit.segmented)
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width + U1.Sepal.Width + 
#        U2.Sepal.Width + U3.Sepal.Width + U1.Petal.Width + U2.Petal.Width + 
#        U3.Petal.Width, data = mfExt)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -1.25915 -0.25375 -0.02634  0.22621  1.25034 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)      3.3287     0.8546   3.895 0.000151 ***
#   Sepal.Width      0.4309     0.3066   1.405 0.162120    
# Petal.Width      0.2362     1.0925   0.216 0.829120    
# U1.Sepal.Width   0.4492     0.8220   0.546 0.585606    
# U2.Sepal.Width  -0.7730     0.9027  -0.856 0.393306    
# U3.Sepal.Width   0.8078     0.6080   1.329 0.186139    
# U1.Petal.Width   1.1081     1.2094   0.916 0.361099    
# U2.Petal.Width  -0.4990     0.3862  -1.292 0.198400    
# U3.Petal.Width  -0.4617     0.4824  -0.957 0.340195    
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.4381 on 141 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7351,  Adjusted R-squared:   0.72 
# F-statistic:  48.9 on 8 and 141 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16        

    predict(fit.segmented, data.frame("Sepal.Width" = 3, "Petal.Width" = 1.8), se.fit = TRUE)
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'U1.Sepal.Width' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to need to create the U1.xx columns by hand in the "newdata" object.

(This seems strange behaviour for to require)

However, you can do this, you could use cut:

```
# new data
newD <- data.frame("Sepal.Width" = 3, "Petal.Width" = 1.8)
# function to get breaks
toBr <- function(name, breaks, values){ cut(values, c(-Inf,breaks,Inf), sprintf("U%s.%s",seq_len(length(breaks)+1)-1,name))}

# use nnet::class.ind to convert from factor to indicator matrix
#  don't really need U0.xxx but no harm keeping
list_results <- lapply(Map(toBr, names(newD), breaks, newD), nnet::class.ind)
# combine with newD and then predict)
predict(fit.segmented,cbind(newD,do.call(cbind, list_results)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you provided returns different fitted values (compared to the ones returned by `fit.segmented$fitted`).